# how to get a base url from a variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In this script, i would like to define the baseURLStatic as http//:%ALLHOST%

```
document.write("<li id='tab"+x+"' onclick='window.location.assign(\""+baseURLStatic+"/"+year+"/home/"+league_id+"#"+x+"\")'>"+mimicHomePageTabs[x]+"</li>\n");
```

I have tried this, but did not work

```
document.write("<li id='tab"+x+"' onclick='window.location.assign(\""+http+"//:"+%ALLHOST%+"/"+year+"/home/"+league_id+"#"+x+"\")'>"+mimicHomePageTabs[x]+"</li>\n");
```

The end result of the url would be this

```
http://%ALLHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%
```

Comment: This is better: `var mimicHomePageTabs = ["Home","Managers", ... ];`

Comment: So does baseURLStatic == baseURL%ALLHOST% ?

Can you give me an example of what it contains?

Comment: %ALLHOST% will pull the dynamic or the static , depending on the page needed......really kooky set up for this site, but it has several pages using both urls for some odd reason example is <a href="http://%STATICHOST%/%YEAR%/live_scoring_summary?L=%LEAGUEID%"> works for the 2013 year, but <a href="http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/live_scoring_summary?L=%LEAGUEID%"> is needed for past seasons  and <a href="http://%ALLHOST%/%YEAR%/live_scoring_summary?L=%LEAGUEID%"> works for every year , so i really need to use ALLHOST

Comment: Does this help? http://jsbin.com/omenof/1/edit

Comment: thanks Sukima, but with that the tabs will not even populate , they must be numbered like so [0]="Home"

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear of what i wanted to achieve